# Sort an array of array by 2 conditions

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have to sort this

```
ary = [[5, "e", "2"], [2, "r", "="], [2, "y", "2"], [2, "h", "="]]
```

to obtain :

```
# => [[5, "e", "2"], [2, "y", "2"], [2, "h", "="], [2, "r", "="]]
```

If the last element (index 2) is equal to "=" it must be after the array which has the same first element even if the letter is before.
Something like this :

```
ary.each_with_index do |array, index|
  if ary[index][2] == "=" && ary[index][0] == ary[index +1][2]
    a = ary[index]
    b = ary[index +1]
    ary[index] = b
    ary[index+1] = a
  end
end
```

Comment: Looking at the elements with "=", do you want to sort in decreasing order on the first element? When there are ties, sort in increasing order of the second element? Same for elements without `"="`? What about`ary = [[2, "e", "2"], [2, "e", "10"]]`? Please clarify by editing (rather than posting a comment).

Answer (score 2):

I assume that, for elements ending with `"="`, sorting is by decreasing value of the first element (integers) and when there are ties, by increasing order of the second element (strings). Further, I assume sorting is the same for elements not ending with `"="`, except when the first two elements both tie, sorting is by increasing order of the last element (strings).

```
def sort_em(arr)
  arr.sort_by { |n, s1, s2| [s2 == "=" ? 1 : 0, -n, s1, s2] }
end

sort_em [[5, "e", "2"], [2, "r", "="], [2, "y", "2"], [2, "h", "="]]
  #=> [[5, "e", "2"], [2, "y", "2"], [2, "h", "="], [2, "r", "="]]
```

See the third paragraph of the doc for [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for an explanation of how arrays are ordered when sorting.

To ensure elements ending with `"="` come last in the sort, I've simply added `1` (`0`) at the beginning of array in `sort_by`'s block for arrays ending (not ending) with `"="`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) and provide your own block for sorting:

```
ary.sort do |a, b| 
  if a[2] == '=' && b[2] != '='
    # a has '=' => a > b 
    1
  elsif b[2] == '=' && a[2] != '='
    # b has '=' => a < b 
    -1
  else
    # This is hit if neither a nor b have a '=' OR when both do.
    # Use default comparison operator
    # but restrict it to the second element of the array
    a[1] <=> b[1]
  end
end
```

The block needs to return a value that is `1`, `-1` or `0`. Based on this, the values are placed in order.

- 1: a > b
- -1: a < b
- 0: a = b